# redraw full calendar on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

FullCalendar v3.0.0

When a page is zoomed in to 150% and the page has a set of 12 calendars on it, then the calendars appear shrunken from left to right, also in jsFiddle they do the same thing which makes showing this very easy.

If you click my fiddle below you will see that the table of calendars are displayed incorrectly, but when you drag the bar between the display and the JS the calendar will redraw and appear as squares to the best they can. Likewise, when you have a table of these twelve calendars on a page and you set your zoom to 150% then reload you will see the same issue however if you change your zoom either more or less it fixes the calendars into squares as best it can.

TLDR;
Calendars look screwy for the first 3 months on load when settings are set to zoomed in.

Id like to do some sort of redraw on load so the calendars will fix themselves just like when you change the zoom level or drag the display bigger/smaller.

Ive tried `.('render')` `.('rerenderevent')` etc. all to no avail.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/9wkwv33k/)

**HTML:**

```
<section id="calendar-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <table id="calendar-table">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="calendar0" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar1" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar2" class="calendar"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="calendar3" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar4" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar5" class="calendar"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="calendar6" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar7" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar8" class="calendar"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="calendar9" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar10" class="calendar"></div></td>
            <td><div id="calendar11" class="calendar"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
    calendarDate = moment().month(i).year(2016);
   $('#calendar' + i).fullCalendar({
     theme: true,
     header: {
       left: '',
       center: 'title',
       right: ''
     },
     defaultDate: calendarDate
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by resetting the aspect ratio for all calendars on load:

```
$(".fc").fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 1.25);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/9wkwv33k/3/)

[FullCalendar Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/)